# HTML / CSS center NavBar <UL>

Tags: html, css

I would like to know how I can center my navbar. I am using `display: inline-block;` but it looks like it does not help. I tried looking for padding problems but no luck. Somehow it's too far from left.

[image]

```css
.main {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

#navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #2e2e2e;
  color: #bbb;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#navbar ul a {
  color: #bbb;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#navbar ul li {
  float: button;
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#navbar ul li:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #00939C;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar" class="main">
  <ul id=ul_navbar>
    <a href="#">
      <li>Domov</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li><del>Preklady</del></li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li><del>Chat</del></li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li><del>O nás</del></li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li><del>F.A.Q.</del></li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li><del>Podporte nás</del></li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: FWIW, `<a>` is not a valid child element of `<ul>`, only `<li>`.

Comment: @hungerstar  it is INSIDE #NAVBAR find all UL tags and find all A under UL its normal css style =\  its like ( selection ul a li {} )

Comment: Your CSS might work and browsers are very forgiving but it's invalid HTML, please reference [**MDN <ul>**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) for **permitted content**. Just pointing it out for future reference is all.

Comment: @hungerstar thx i just moved from java to HTML/ CSS and PHP and still just learning this will help me :) a lot cause i never know this rules :o, thanks :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the HTML is invalid and the questioner does not know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, your HTML and CSS are both invalid. You should look at fixing them, but it's not what's causing your problem.

The imbalance is caused by default padding on the `ul` - if you use

```
#navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

It will even it up for you.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected results, use below option

```
  #navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

Codepen- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/pwExdX

Comment: @PatrikHorváth i have updated with padding , please check it once now